Getting an average calculated provided the number in the column is only counted once for each distinct value (index) in another column
Total newbie here, learning by making tons of mistakes.
I've set up a power Bi dashboard linked to the results from a Microsoft Forms.
As there's many multiple choice answers in this form, i've had to use the 'split column to rows' quite a lot in order to present the values from the multiple choice correctly in the dashboard. So far, so good.
I've made sure to set up a column with unique Index per original answer in the form, in order to be able to represent total numbers correctly and calculate averages. Totals are going great...averages however, not so much.
The summarization on the index column is Count [distinct]
The summarization on the satisfaction score is Average
See an example below



Index
Training satisfaction score




1
80


1
80


1
80


2
95


3
100


3
100


4
75


5
100


5
100


5
100


5
100



In this case, i'd like the average of 80+95+100+75+100 = 90
Distinct values are the condition for index column, but it can be that the value in the training satisfactions score is duplicated which is fine, as long as index is different.
I'm using the below dax,
but in some calculations (depending on the filter) i'm getting even averages over 100%
Average Training satisfaction = AVERAGEX(SUMMARIZE('Tracker EMEA 24',
   'Tracker EMEA 24'[Index], 
   'Tracker EMEA 24'[Training satisfaction score]), 
   'Tracker EMEA 24'[Training satisfaction score])

What am i doing wrong?

you can try this
average = average('Tracker EMEA 24'[Training satisfaction score])

avearge2 = averagex(VALUES('Tracker EMEA 24'[Index]),[average])



Thanks! It's giving me the exact same results. On one page, where i have a page filter that another column [Retailer audience] is not blank, the average ends up being +100%. Could the page filter be impacting the wrong result?

could you pls update the sample data and expected output?

Apologies for the late response. I've plowed through all the data to check if any mistakes were made, i believe someone manually adapted certain numbers in the master file causing the calculation error. Since i've corrected that, everything works perfectly. Thanks for your support!
